# Formulario en dos pasos, Mostrar imagen en tiempo real entre Campos necesidades y Campos de contacto y Submit

Tags: html, formularios

estoy armando un formulario, con detalles sobre preferencias que determinan un producto recomendado , eso ya se define al completar los primeros campos de formulario, y quisiera que cuando se completen esos campos se resuelva mostrando una imagen del producto recomendado, en tiempo real, (segùn las selecciones que se hayan hecho) sin necesidad de presionar ningún botón, y y luego mas campos de contacto y el Submit/envío del formulario.

Gracias, 
Saludos

cree un archivo aqui .
https://jsfiddle.net/b6a2mou8/29/#&togetherjs=iGN7kRJmvd

```
<form>
<div>
<p>Manten presionada la tecla Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) para seleccionar mas de una opcion.</p>
<select multiple>
<option value="Opcion1">Opcion1</option>
<option value="Opcion2">Opcion2</option>
<option value="Opcion3">Opcion3</option>
<option value="Opcion4">Opcion4</option>
<option value="Opcion5">Opcion5</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="row"></div>

<fieldset>
<div>

<legend>Elige una Opcion</legend>

        <div>
        <input type="radio" id="Opcion1" name="Opcion1" checked /><label for="Opcion1">Opcion1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Opcion2" name="Opcion2" /><label for="Opcion2">Opcion2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="OPcion3" name="OPcion3" /><label for="OPcion3">OPcion3</label>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="row"></div>   
<fieldset>
<legend>Elige un caso</legend>

        <div>
        <input type="radio" id="Caso1" name="Caso1" checked />
        <label for="Caso1">Caso1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Caso2" name="Caso2" />
        <label for="Caso2">Caso2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Caso3" name="Caso3" />
        <label for="Caso3">Caso3</label>
    </div>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Elige una Situacion</legend>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="Situacion1" name="Situacion1" checked />
        <label for="Situacion1">Situacion1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Situacion2" name="Situacion2" />
        <label for="Situacion2">Situacion2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="Situacion3" name="Situacion3" />
        <label for="Situacion3">Situacion3</label>
    </div>

</fieldset>

<p>Nuestra recomendacion para usted es:  Aqui Quiero que aparezca una imagen del producto. Lo ideal seria que que fuera en tiempo real , sin necesidad de accionar un boton, como respuesta por completar los campos: </p><br>
```

Una vez que vio el producto Se completa el formulario con los datos de contacto y otras necesarias y se procede al envia con la informacion

```
<div class="row">
  <p> Los siguientes datos son necesarios para cotizarle:</p>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-center form-style-10">
<div class="row">
<div class="section"><span>2</span>Flota</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="row">
<li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" ><span>Coches<span><select/><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select>
<li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" >
<span>barcos<span>
<select/>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>                
</select>
<div class="row">
<li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" ><span>Motos<span><select/><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>    <option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select>

<fieldset>
<legend>Tipo de Factura</legend>

    <div>
<input type="radio" id="facturaA" name="facturaA" checked />
<label for="facturaA">facturaA</label>
    </div>

    <div>
<input type="radio" id="facturaB" name="facturaB" />
<label for="facturaB">facturaB</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="facturaC" name="facturaC" />
        <label for="facturaC">facturaC</label>
    </div>

</fieldset>

<div class="row">
<div class="inner-wrap">
<div class="section"><span>2</span>datos de contacto</div>
<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Nombre<input type="text" name="nombre" /></label>
    <label>Telefono<input type="phone" name="telefono" /></label>
    <label>email<input type="email" name="email" /></label>
</div>


</div>


<div class="row ">
<div id="error" style="text-align:center"></div>

<div class="col-lg-12"><button class="btn btn-submit" name="submitform" style="background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.0);" type="submit">        <label>enviar</label></button></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: No creo que nadie te entienda, puedes definir, primero, en dónde están esas imágenes, segundo cuales son los campos que al llenarse te sugieren una imagen, así como lo pusiste dudo que alguien te apoye

Comment: Sí es que te estoy entendiendo con lo de tiempo real, es que queréis que aparezca una imagen después de la selección de 3 controles de formulario, bueno en tal caso lo mas lógico sería pensar que ese resultado sería obtenido con interacción de la base de datos, para lo cual deberías hacer una petición **Ajax** para invocar la imagen sin necesidad de refrescar el navegador, pero si no lo requieres y las posibilidades son muy pocas bastaría con emplear Javascript (de preferencia con algún framework como JQuery).

Comment: Hola Alberto., los campos son los primeros, estan separados en dos partes el formulario. Un par de opciones en grupos radio y otro par en seleccion. Y al completar estos aparece una imagen de sugerencia de entre cuatro o cinco. Y despues otros campos para contactarnos y brindarle asesoramiento. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Jorge,  se trata de un formulario que brinda una sugerencia de entre cuatro o cinco imagenes q pueden estar en el servidor. . Que le muestran q producto cumple los requisitos de sus selecciones y tambien algun texto q invite a terminar el formulario para q lo contacten.

Comment: Hola Jorge,  se trata de un formulario que brinda una sugerencia de entre cuatro o cinco imagenes q pueden estar en el servidor. . Que le muestran q producto cumple los requisitos de sus selecciones y tambien algun texto q invite a terminar el formulario para q lo contacten. Supongo que para esto seria suficiente con la  segunda opcion que propones para invocar a la imagen sin refrescar la pagina.  Gracias